# Combine signals in ReactiveCocoa to a new one that fires when all change

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to learn ReactiveCocoa and I'm writing a simple Space Invaders clone, based on a Ray Wenderlich tutorial.
Lately during the development, I faced an issue I can't resolve.
Basically I've two signals:

- a tap gesture signal
- a timed sequence that fires every second

What I want to achieve is to combine these signals in a new one, that fires when both the signals change:
is it possible?
I saw the combineLatest method, but the block is execute whenever any signals change.

My wanted pseudocode is:

```
RACSignal *updateEventSignal = [RACSignal interval:1 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];
RACSignal *gestureSignal = [[UITapGestureRecognizer new] rac_gestureSignal];
[[RACSignal combineBoth:@[gestureSignal, updateEventSignal]
                   reduce:^id(id tap, id counter){
                       return tap;
                   }]
 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     NSLog(@"Tapped [%@]", x);
 }];
```

Probably I can achieve the same result in other way or this is not the expected behaviour or ReactiveCocoa, but at this point I wonder if I'm in the right *reactive* track or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `+combineLatest:reduce:`, you want `+zip:reduce:`. Zip requires that all the signals change before reducing and sending a new value.

Comment: Clever.
I didn't find the zip in documentation, just glimpses in header files, so I didn't notice its property.

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't actually care about the values from the timer, `-sample:` may do what you want:

```
[[gestureSignal
    sample:updateEventSignal]
    subscribeNext:^(id tap) {
        NSLog(@"Tapped [%@]", tap);
    }];
```

This will forward the *latest* value from `gestureSignal` whenever `updateEventSignal` fires.

Comment: It should be perfect, but after tapped once, it continues to sample the same value, each second.
Is there an way to reset the original signal?

Comment: Ah, no, the operator isn't really meant for that. It sounds like `+zip:` is a better option, then.

Answer (score 1):

```
   [[[[RACSignal zip:@[RACObserve(self, minimum), RACObserve(self, maximum), 
RACObserve(self, average)]] skip:1] reduceEach:^id{
            return nil;
        }] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            [self buildView]; //called once, while all three values were changed.
        }];
```