# ReactiveCocoa CombineLatest: and Zip:

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I have the same problem as this post, [Combine signals in ReactiveCocoa to a new one that fires when all change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144752/combine-signals-in-reactivecocoa-to-a-new-one-that-fires-when-all-change)

So I changed to use zip: the the odd problem is the second signals data is not latest one. I put a log in the second signal's map code, it's the latest. E.g.

Signal A, Signal B

```
[self rac_liftSelector:@selector(doTask:) withSignals:[RACSignal zip:@[A, B]      
reduce^id(NSNumber* a, NSNumber* b){
   a// is updated to latest
   b// is the old value
}];
```

In Signal B, I put log found b value is updated.
  If I changed back to CombineLatest: b is updated but a is old value and the signal is not triggered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`+[RACSignal zip:]` doesn't always give you the latest value on each of the signals you pass into it. It gives you the *next* value from each signal. That means that if you have the following marble diagram:

```
Signal A | -(a0)-------------(a1)-----x
         |
Signal B | ----(b0)-(b1)-(b2)----(b3)--->
         |
 zip:A,B | ----(a0,b0)-------(a1,b1)--x
         |
         +-------------------------------
              -- Time -->
```

Your signal will be sent `(a0, b0)` when `b0` is sent, then `(a1, b1)` when `a1` is sent, and then no more values will be sent because `Signal A` completes after only two values.

`+[RACSignal combineLatest:reduce:]`, on the other hand, will always give you the latest value on each of the signals you pass into it whenever *either* signal sends a value (after all signals have sent at least one value):

```
Signal A | -(a0)-----------------------(a1)-----x
         |
Signal B | ----(b0)----(b1)----(b2)------------(b3)---->
         |
cl/r:A,B | ----(a0,b0)-(a0,b1)-(a0,b2)-(a1,b2)-(a1,b3)->
         |
         +----------------------------------------------
              -- Time -->
```