# How to zip RACObserve with "return" correctly?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to modify existing code and having trouble with it.

I need to handle some extra info with observable value.
I'm trying to implement it using `+(RACSignal*)zip:`

```
RACSignal* signal = [RACSignal zip:@[RACObserve(item, value), [RACSignal return:object]]];
```

But resulting signal fires only once. How to make it work?

ReactiveCocoa 2.4.7 used in project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you managed to solve it for your use case but just in case someone wants to zip two signals and also have a return come through with them, you can use `repeat`.

Like so: `[RACSignal zip:@[signal1, [RACSignal return:@YES].repeat, signal2]];`

Answer (score 1):

I'm resolved this problem using `+(RACSignal*)combineLatest:` ([ReactiveCocoa docs](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#combining-latest-values)). In this case it works like intended.

Related question: [Combine signals in ReactiveCocoa to a new one that fires when all change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144752/combine-signals-in-reactivecocoa-to-a-new-one-that-fires-when-all-change)
Situation is opposite to mine.